# Passing character array to a function returns warning

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, getchar, function-definition

Currently completing my C homework for the week and i'm messing about with pointers for the first time properly.

We are told to create a main function to deal with our readLine function thats premade for us (we edit a few things, like the if statement in the while loop).

When trying to compile i am given the error "/usr/include/stdio.h:356:43: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
356 | extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);

What would i have to do to fix this? I think its something to do with how im calling readLine. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int readLine(char *s, int MAX){
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && i<MAX){
        if (*s >= MAX){
            printf("input too long!");
            return -1;
        }
        c = *(s+i);
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int main(){
    int MAX = 20;
    char s[MAX];
    printf(readLine(s, MAX));
}
```

Comment: `readLine` returns an `int`, so what would you expect `printf(readLine(s, MAX));` to do? You'd need something like `printf("%d\n", readLine(s, MAX));` or `readLine(s, MAX); printf("%s\n", s);` depending on what you're trying to print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returns an integer but you are going to output a string. So write

```
readLine(s, MAX);
puts( s );
```

Also this if statement

```
    if (*s >= MAX){
```

does not make sense.

And instead of

```
c = *(s+i);
```

you have to write

```
*(s+i) = c;
```

And within the while loop you need to increase the variable `i`.

Comment: I've changed the if statement to use c instead of *s as c is the input we are testing for length. I think i just need a nap haha

Comment: @IsmaeelAli Using c instead of *s in the if statement also does not make sense.

Comment: I was just about to ask another question. how do i check for if the input is greater than max?

Comment: would i check against i?

Comment: @IsmaeelAli It can not be greater due to the condition of the while loop while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && i<MAX){

Comment: i've ammended the while loop so it only has the first condition now

Comment: @IsmaeelAli As you said the function was premade for you. So do not change it and say the author of the function that he should go out from programming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248891/discussion-between-ismaeel-ali-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @IsmaeelAli  I am sorry. I have no time.

Comment: Understandable, i understand everything now. many thanks buddy